# Song Chords lyrics formatting preview not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, markdown

Hello i am facing issue while formatting the song text and lyrics. I want when user type something and it will refelect to preview area but that preview is working but problem is in formatting.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $source.keyup(transformText)
  transformText()
})

const $source = $('#editText')
const $dest = $('#preview')

function transformText() {
  let markdown = marked($source.val());
  markdown = replaceChordWords(markdown)
  $dest.html(markdown)
}

function replaceChordWords(input) {
  let markdown = input
  const chordWordRegex = /\[(.*?)\]\w+/g
  
  markdown = markdown.replaceAll(chordWordRegex, (input) => {
    const chordRegex = /\[(.*?)\]/
    const inputSplit = input.split(chordRegex).filter(x => x !== '')
    return `<span class="chord-word">
      <span class="chord" data-uncopyable-text="${inputSplit[0]}"></span>
      ${inputSplit[1]}
    </span>`
  })

  return markdown
}
```

```css
.chord-word {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  position: relative;
}

.chord {
  color: #1f45ff;
  white-space: pre;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 17px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  white-space: wrap;
}

[data-uncopyable-text]::after {
  content: attr(data-uncopyable-text);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-row">
  <div class="col-4">
    <textarea id="editText" rows="20" cols="38" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">1
            D[D]earest Lord, You’ve c[Bm]alled us here,
            And o[G]pened up Your h[A]eart.
            O the joy to hear Your call
            And enter in the Ark.
            Saving us from day to day
            O Lord, this is Your way.
            In Yourself we stay afloat,
            Above this wicked age tod[D - D7]ay.

            Th[G]ank You L[A]ord, in Your e[D]yes w[D/C]e find gr[Bm]ace,
             And with open hearts we come to You.
             Regardless what our friends might say to us or do,
            O Lord Jesus, we love You.

           2
            Seeking of this age to taste,
             And of it have a part.
             If we only knew, dear Lord,
             The ways we grieve Your heart.
            We would come and turn to You
            With a repenting heart,
            And would give ourselves to be
            With you, O Lord, inside the Ark.

            3
            Praise You Lord, we’re safe in You;
            Outside death-waters pour.
            Many things that I once loved
            Are on the ocean floor.
            Keep us open to You Lord,
            Don’t let us miss the mark.
            Hallelujah, praise the Lord,
            We’re here within the church, the Ark.
  </textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <br>
    <p id="preview"></p>
  </div>
</form>
```

MY current Ouput is :-

[image]

Excepted Output is :-

[image]

Comment: I placed your code in a snippet, however you've not included the `marked()` function so there's an error. Can you please edit to include that function so we can see a working example of the code

Comment: Thanks for the edit but `marked` is still not defined so we still can't run the demo

Comment: <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js"></script>  i am not able to add this script file

Comment: Of course you're able to. Not sure what went wrong when you tried, but I did it for you this time.

Comment: https://songbase.life/admin/example i want same output like given this example. can you help me?

Comment: Why not just copy the code from that site then? Of course you might have to check if there's a license, or copyright or anything like that

Comment: @ADyson its in reactjs but i need to do in jquery or javascript